# Realm Fetched Results Controller

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new at realm and previously used Core Data. As far as i understand, the analogue to `NSFetchedResultsController` is the following code:

```
    observationToken = realm.objects(DBMessage.self).observe { (changes) in
        switch changes {
        case .initial(let messages):
            print("fetched - \(Array(messages))")
        case .update(let results, deletions: let deletions, insertions: let insertions, modifications: let modifications):
            let updates = Array(results)
            print("updates started - \(Thread.isMainThread)")
            insertions.forEach({
                print("updates - \(updates[$0])")
            })
            print("updates finished")
        case .error(let error):
            print("observation error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that in `case .initial` realm fetches all objects from database. Is there any way to set up notifications on objects of particular type and predicate without fetching all cached objects? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can declare collection observation after applying filters and sorts:

```
// just an example
observationToken = realm.objects(DBMessage.self)
    .filter("isRead == false")
    .sort(byKeyPath: "insertedAt", ascending: false)
    .observe { [weak self] changes in
        switch changes {
        case .initial(let messages):
            // initial collection
            break
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            break
        case .error(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: But initial collection would be loaded anyway? And there is no way to add observer and receive events without fetching objects from database?

Comment: @NikitaPronchik Realm collections are lazily loaded (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) so unless you access the collection items,  they are not read from DB.